HttpClient.GetAsync Fails for Specific URL
For this valid url:
https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES

Calling HttpClient's GetAsync method fails with a 500 error.
Minimal reproduction:
var client = new HttpClient();
var res = await client.GetAsync(
    "https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES");

Console.WriteLine(res.StatusCode); // InternalServerError

Which, at first glance makes you think the problem must be Spotify's. After all, it is Spotify's server that is returning the 500 error.
However, every other method I've tried to fetch that URL works just fine

try it in your browser, it works
try it with curl, it works:

curl "https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES"


try it with javascript, it works:

fetch("https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES")
    .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})


try it in PowerShell, it works:

Invoke-WebRequest "https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES"

It is only in C# where the failure occurs.
What is a basic C# request doing different than all these other methods?

The HttpClient has different headers compared to others. For example, the User-Agent header will be empty, which might cause some errors.

Turns out the issue is that C# doesn't put in a default user-agent header.
Adding:
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("smh");

solves the issue.

It's always important to keep in mind web servers don't actually know who they're talking to. All they know is the information provided to them in a request. So if the web server appears to be treating one client different, all you need do is examine the request to see what's different about it. Fiddler and Wireshark are good tools for that.

If you would look at request in browser's dev tools and/or at copied cURL request, you would see a ton of headers being set.
Spotify (and other) server looks for particular headers to serve a response, so you need to set those headers in C# HttpClient as well.
Look at below code snippet, that successfully fetches data (just as in browser):
using var client = new HttpClient();
// Set the request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "sp_t=32d30582c0e595b1b03500e38cd7219b; _gcl_au=1.1.1632377271.1728126146; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Sat+Oct+05+2024+13%3A02%3A29+GMT%2B0200+(czas+%C5%9Brodkowoeuropejski+letni)&version=202405.2.0&browserGpcFlag=0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=31c916af-3bbf-40c7-bf7c-a365cbc6aece&interactionCount=1&isAnonUser=1&landingPath=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2F&groups=s00%3A1%2Cf00%3A0%2Cm00%3A0%2Ct00%3A0%2Cf11%3A0%2Ci00%3A0%2CV2STACK3%3A0%2CV2STACK11%3A0%2CV2STACK20%3A0%2Cm03%3A1; sp_landing=http%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fapi%2Foembed%3Fsp_cid%3D32d30582c0e595b1b03500e38cd7219b%26device%3Ddesktop");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Priority", "u=0, i");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Opera\";v=\"113\", \"Chromium\";v=\"127\"");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.6533.120 Safari/537.36");

// Set the request URL
var url = "https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fplaylist%2F37i9dQZF1DWTggY0yqBxES";

// Make the GET request
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

// Ensure the request was successful
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// Read and display the response content
var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

